# Is the pointer calloc function return a pointer vector? (C language)

Tags: c, pointers, calloc

I'm trying to understand a c code, (SimpleScalar, bpred.c), there is the thing that confuses me a lot:

```
    int *shiftregs;
    shiftregs = calloc(1, sizeof(int));

    int l1index, l2index;
    l1index = 0; 
    l2index = shiftregs[l1index];
```

I delete some code that might not help. After the `calloc` call, `*shiftregs` becomes a pointer array? And what is the value of `l2index`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "a pointer vector"? There's no such thing in C.

Comment: sorry I mean pointer array

Comment: `*shiftregs` is an `int`. `shiftregs` is a pointer to `int`. An `int*` may point to the first element of an array of `int`.

Comment: If I change    shiftregs = calloc(1, sizeof(int)) to    shiftregs = calloc(5, sizeof(int));  shiftregs[#] means the content in the location? Does shiftregs become int array?

Comment: No. You defined `shiftregs` as a pointer, and it remains a pointer no matter what you assign to it. Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `shiftregs` is a pointer to an `int`, `*shiftregs` is an `int`.

Since `calloc` guarantees that the memory it allocates is set to `0`, and you've allocated enough memory to refer to `shiftregs[0]`, `l2index` will be `0` (assuming `calloc` didn't fail and return `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

The `calloc()` function is being used to allocate a dynamic array of zeroed integers that can be referenced via the pointer `shiftregs`.

The value in `l2index` is going to be zero unless the allocation failed (`calloc()` returned NULL). If the allocation failed, you invoke undefined behaviour; anything could happen, but your program will probably crash.  Check the allocation so that it doesn't crash!

Answer (score 0):

`l2index` is 0. `calloc` set memory to zero. Following is Linux Programmer's Manual:

> calloc()  allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size
>   bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory
>   is set to zero.  If nmemb or  size  is  0,  then  calloc()  returns
>   either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully
>   passed to free().

Answer (score 0):

Check if the calloc() return NULL.
If so, the "l2index = shiftregs[l1index];"will crash, for you try to get value from a NULL point(shiftregs).
If not, as they said l2index will be 0.